# Get a warning when I run "brew doctor" in terminal

Tags: terminal, command, homebrew

I'm installing Homebrew on my Mac. I installed it correctly, but when I run "brew doctor" in the command line. I get this message:

```
Warning: Setting DYLD_* vars can break dynamic linking.
Set variables:
    DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Does anybody how I can fix this warning? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here in the bug tracker on Github dealing exactly with this issue:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/18990#issuecomment-29181482

Try the following after opening the terminal

```
$ sudo grep -rnI "DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" /
```

Then let this run for a few hours, while it scans every text file on your system for this setting. Once you find where it is, you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did check this article before I posted. I did some of the suggestions. Still get the same error.

Comment: Ok updated my answer with a brute force method to finding where this environment var is being set.

Comment: Hi, I ran that command like you said to debug where the file is. I found that every instance of "DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" was in XCode. Here is what the terminal returned: [link](http://pastebin.com/bXzLe0w4) on Pastebin. What would I do next to fix this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't appear to be set anywhere in those...strange. You could always try the following when running brew: `unset DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH && brew doctor`

Comment: I tried that and it worked. But will this mess up my Ruby developer environment in any way? I'm installing rvm and rails. And I needed homebrew of course.

Comment: In that github link, they recommend you don't ever have that environment variable set - not just during brew installs, but when running rails etc. As a workaround you could create a simple bash script for starting rails. It's only purpose will be to call `unset DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` - then the second line of the script will launch rails.

Comment: Also as a last resort, I would try opening `~/.bash_profile` and check if `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` is set there. Not sure if `grep` somehow passed over that file